# Get item from array and delete it until the array is empty for Discord JS bot

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot in JavaScript. I'm trying to make a function where every day at a certain time it sends a new questions (Question of the day).

All the questions are available in an array. I want to let the code choose a random item from the array and send it in the discord chat. After it sent the message, I want to have it deleted from the array so that it can't choose the questions again.

I thought it would be easy but I can't figure it out with the help of Google.

```
let scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob('*/5 * * * * *', () => {
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('766724832334970942');
  const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('790532358574178314');

  let questions = ['Question A', 'Question B', 'Question B'];
  let questionsEmpty = [''];

  if (questions === '') {
    channel.send('Unfortunatly, there are no more questions')
  }
  else {
    let randomQuestionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
    channel.send(questions[randomQuestionIndex]);
    questions.splice(randomQuestionIndex, 1);
  }
}, null, true, 'Europe/Amsterdam');
```

This is what I tried to make, but I obviously doesn't work.

Comment: You say it doesnt work but you dont explain what does it do and what is expected.

Comment: `if (questions === '') {`? How could an array ever equal an empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time your cron job runs, it recreates the questions array, you need the array to be declared *outside* of that function

```
let questions = ['Question A', 'Question B', 'Question B'];
let scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob('*/5 * * * * *', () => {
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('766724832334970942');
  const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('790532358574178314');

  if (questions.length === 0) {
    channel.send('Unfortunatly, there are no more questions')
  }
  else {
    let randomQuestionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
    channel.send(questions[randomQuestionIndex]);
    questions.splice(randomQuestionIndex, 1);
  }
}, null, true, 'Europe/Amsterdam');
```

Comment: I feel so stupid... It works flawlessly. Thank you so so much!